# How to filter a table onto new tab in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

Excel has been out of my scope for a long time, and this feels very simple. Looking for the formula to filter a list, but the results are on a new tab.

Closest thing I have found is this [FILTER](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) function, but as the site reads it's a new feature to be released in 2019. So I do not have access to it because I'm using **Excel 2013**.

I'm trying to filter on a field of Date Ranges, so all entries in the current week would be filtered to the new tab.

[image]

So filter with dates for the week of 06 Oct 2019 to 12 Oct 2019 on a new tab would return the top 2 rows only.

I have tried the FILTER function, it doesn't work in MS Excel 2013. I also reviewed VLOOKUP, nope. I know PIVOT is not what i want. I want to avoid VBA scripting because this will go to a non-developer eventually.

Lastly filter the current table will not meet my objective.

Comment: You want `Advanced Filter` it is on the data tab.  It will allow you to set a filter and filter the data onto the new tab.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sorry that will not meet my objective. Advanced Filter only applies if the new table is on the current page - I have attempted this, and the only way I got it working was keeping the data on the same tab. I also want this filter to auto update if the dates are changed. So a formula function is the way to go.

Comment: You are correct that Advanced filter is not live and must be run on the change, but it will allow the use on a different page than the data: https://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/

Comment: Yes I was taught how to do that. When you do thing out of order MS Excel can be finicky, I thought the last option to put data in a location would of worked but it didn`t, I had to start off on the tab where I wanted the data to be displayed. The MS Excel Order of Operations. I do have a solution. I will share it once I have a free moment.

Comment: "I know PIVOT is not what i want. I want to avoid VBA" you just exclude both viable options. What's your problem with pivot table? If definitely not go for functions, although it's possible to use it'll result very complex formulas and they need to be filled down as new data is entered. I'd go for a pivot table and a short macro to update it whenever its sheet is activate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies in the delay for responding.

Used a similar technique as provided by the @Rajesh Sinha below.

replaced the  `Sheet1!$A$2:$C$10` with a defined table using the [following steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-table-in-excel-bf0ce08b-d012-42ec-8ecf-a2259c9faf3f). In the menu bar the Table Design option is available and there is a property for Table Name. Used the default value of **Table1**.

At the top of the page declared 2x variables **Start_Date** which had a formula

> =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)

and End_Date, with a  formula

> =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),3)+7

Applied the use of the [AGGREGATE ftn](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) to compare the variables of the due date, and displayed the values in the new tab only if due in the next 7 days (aka the end date). This applies the use of SMALL if reviewing the associated documents.

> =IFERROR(@INDEX(Table1,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((Table1[Dates]>=START_DATE)*(Table1[Dates]<=END_DATE))*ROW(Table1)-ROW(Table1[#Headers]),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"--")

For each column copied, the only reference that changed above was the COLUMNS.

For the second column `COLUMNS($A,B)` and third column was `COLUMNS($A,C)`

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this Array (CSE) Formula in `New Tab` to get records from `Source Tab`, between two dates.*

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$10, SMALL(IF((Sheet1!C2:$C$10>=$A$1)*(Sheet1!C2:$C$10<=$B$1), MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!C2:$C$10), ROW(Sheet1!C2:$C$10)), ""), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),""))}
```

**How it works:**

- Enter Start & End Date in New Tab Cell `A1` & `B1`.

*Instead of using search dates (criteria), using cell reference makes the formula dynamic.*

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, then fill across.
- Adjust Sheet name, Cell references in the formula as needed.